# MySQL Import and replace single columen where multiple condition is met

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to import and replace one column in a table where multiple condition is met?

Lets say I have following two tables:

```
id, name, folder, subfolder, count1, count2
1, A, New,  Car, 3, 5
2, B, Old, MC, 6, 8
3, C, Brand, Cycle, 4, 8



id, name, folder, subfolder, count1, count2
1, A, New,  Car, 0, 0
2, B, Old, MC, 0, 0
3, C, Brand, Cycle, 0, 0
```

What I am looking for is to update and replace count1, count2 values for all entires where name, folder and subfolder values are same as imported table and skip everything else.

I can not use ID as reference as IDs can be different.

Comment: This looks like a simple UPDATE - WHERE the conditions are met. Bit puzzled my the mention of IMPORT though..

Comment: Do you have any example for this sample update? :)

Comment: Exactly how can I specifiy to update if fields are same as imported table?

Comment: The manual is  good place to start https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html AND have you come across the term ALIAS

Comment: You need to use the concept of update along with table join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` with `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE elbat1
       INNER JOIN elbat2
                  ON elbat2.name = elbat1.name
                     AND elbat2.folder = elbat1.folder
                     AND elbat2.subfolder = elbat1.subfolder
       SET elbat1.count1 = elbat2.count1,
           elbat1.count2 = elbat2.count2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a935af6b946feb8a14acb78b2fc921f7)

Comment: Thanks this become solution to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following query to get an idea of how to proceed:

```
UPDATE 
existing_data
INNER JOIN new_import ON new_import.id = existing_data.id 
SET  existing_data.count2 = new_import.count2,
     existing_data.count1 = new_import.count1
WHERE existing_data.id = 1
```

Please look into the concent of table join and update being used together.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have not tested this but I am sure it works too.